# How to know ubuntu 32 or 64 from livecd

Tags: server, versions

I am running a ubuntu server. From live CD(32bit) how to know version server(32 or 64bit). What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: I would search for the cpu model on the makers web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out your CPU Architecture, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

And you will see this:

[image]

If it says 48 bits virtual, the its 64bit capable, otherwise it will say 32 bits virtual

**To find out your if the CD you have is 32bit or 64bit do:**

Look in the CD for a folder called `.disk`

[image]

Inside that folder there is a file called `info`

[image]

The contents of that file will show you the right Architecture 32bit or 64bit

[image]

Comment: He knows that the CD is 32-bit but he wants to know if the computer is 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
file /sbin/init
```

The response will either mention 32-bit or 64-bit after "ELF"

Answer (score 0):

**How To Find Out If Your Computer Has a 32bit or 64bit Cpu:**

In Terminal Type: "sudo lshw -C cpu"

It will say "width=32bit" or "width=64bit"

Sources:
http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=699.0

**How To Find Out If You Are Running A 32bit or 64bit Linux Operating System:**

In terminal type:
"uname -a"

sources:
http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=688.0

**How To Find Out If An Ubuntu Install Is 32bit Or 64bit From Another Ubuntu Install:**

In Terminal Type:
"cd /media/nameofdrive/lib64"

"nameofdrive" being the name of the partition your installation is on.

If you get a response that says "/media/nameofdrive/lib64" then it's a 64bit install.
If you get a response that says "error no such file or directory" then it's a 32bit install.

A 32bit install will have lib, but a 64bit install will have lib and lib64 directories.

PS: to go back to the default directory type in terminal:
"cd /"

Sources:
candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=709.0

Comment: Don't use name tags! Haven't you read the FAQ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
grep -o -w 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
```

If the output is `lm` then you have 64 bit else if no output then you are 32 bit.